# How to re-initialize fancytree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I have to reinitialize a fancytree in dependence of the choosen dropdown option.

Every time I change the option, I call the function getTree() in wich I initialize

$("#tree").fancytree({.....});

The problem is that the tree tries to load the data also from the previous selection because it's already initialized, so I have to re-initialize it in some way (I want to render new tree every time I change the dropdown option).

Somebody could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could reload the tree with new source

```
tree.reload({
  url: ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could update source option (no need tree reload) if you are not using lazyLoad

```
$("#tree").fancytree("option", "source",[{…},{…},…])
```